# Edit a SharePoint List with InfoPath Form 2010 (Auto Populate Fields From List)

Tags: 2010, infopath

I am using SharePoint and InfoPath Designer 2010.

I have a SharePoint list called DiskInfo and the columns are: Client, RAM, CPU.

The Client field is a drop down box connected to another master client List, which populates based on the fields in that list.

I would like to have the user selects a client, it fills in the RAM and CPU fields with the data from the DiskInfo list.

Then the user can view those fields, or update them and click submit and have that update the DiskInfo list.

I cannot seem to get my rules correct so that the RAM and CPU fields populate with the correct information for editing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask here is master/detail (aka parent/child) relation.

In Infopath form, while it is possible to view/show multiple list items based on a selected item of master list, editing/updating in infopath forms OOTB (and/or purely in Infopath) is possibe only on per list item while you basically ask about both viewing and editing multiple list items in one purely Infopath bottle.

So, first you should know what you can do, then to formulate your wishes according to that and plan your howtos. Or, obviously use other, non-purely(OOTB)-Infopath approaches.

One of the approaches I use for such cases is mixed approach of inserting Infopath form web parts into ASPX sharepint web part pages. Though, it is unrelated to the scope of your question.

Another approach about which I've read but never tried myself is to use [QDabra Qrules](http://www.qdabra.com/en/products/qRules_new.aspx).

There are other possible approaches but none of purely and/or OOTB (out-of-the-box) Infopath one as you formulated it.